# unable to get tensorflow working "KeyError: "Couldn't find field google.protobuf.GeneratedCodeInfo.Annotation.path"

Tags: macos, python-2.7, tensorflow

I cannot get tensorflow to install, this is the error message i'm getting:

```
dhcp-3-6:~ M$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in     <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line  49, in <module>
from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-  packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 10, in <module>
from google.protobuf import descriptor_pb2
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor_pb2.py",  line 1495, in <module>
options=None),
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 505, in __new__
return _message.default_pool.FindFieldByName(full_name)
KeyError: "Couldn't find field   google.protobuf.GeneratedCodeInfo.Annotation.path"
```

I have tried many forms but still cannot see how to get it working. Could you please give me some guidance?

Comment: Did you install from source? What version? Is this inside a virtualenv? What steps did you take starting from a clean environment?

Which path here did you take? https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/get_started/os_setup.html

Comment: Ran into the same error. OS X, python 2.7, installing in a virtualenv.  Tensorflow r0.9. Installed custom protobuf package per these instructions: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#protobuf-library-related-issues